# Save .txt File on IBM Iseries Database from procedure on genexus

Tags: genexus

I am using a procedure to generate a .txt file inside my machine, but what I want  is when the file is generated it'll be saved inside an IBM I series database and not inside mi machine

I am new to genexus and to IBM Iseries  database so I don't know how I can achieve that.

Am using .Net and genexus 10 V3

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the .txt file and then save it in the iSeries in a blob field. In the case that you need to do anything with the file inside the DB you can convert it to base64 before sending it to the iSeries and save it in a longvarchar field.